# ComputerLaunchButtonToolTip Error, whether it is compiler error or Spring Tool Suite IDE error?

Tags: tooltip, compiler-warnings, launch, spring-tool-suite

While coding with the STS IDE, many times this error message is been prompted. Whether it is related to tool tip for java code or compiler error?

[image]

@Kris request hereby I am pasting the complete log details of this error, in comment it is not possible to paste this big error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-05-27 15:42:26.837
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.NameEnvironmentAnswer.<init>([Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/ISourceType;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/AccessRestriction;)V
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.core.codeconversion.ITDAwareNameEnvironment.find(ITDAwareNameEnvironment.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.findType(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2940)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveTypeArgument(TypeReference.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveLeafType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.internalFaultInTypeForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyResolver.resolve(HierarchyResolver.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyResolver.resolve(HierarchyResolver.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyBuilder.buildSupertypes(HierarchyBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.IndexBasedHierarchyBuilder.build(IndexBasedHierarchyBuilder.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.compute(TypeHierarchy.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.refresh(TypeHierarchy.java:1286)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CreateTypeHierarchyOperation.executeOperation(CreateTypeHierarchyOperation.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.newSupertypeHierarchy(SourceType.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.newSupertypeHierarchy(SourceType.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaLaunchableTester.hasSuperclass(JavaLaunchableTester.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaLaunchableTester.test(JavaLaunchableTester.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.Property.test(Property.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateOr(CompositeExpression.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.OrExpression.evaluate(OrExpression.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.AndExpression.evaluate(AndExpression.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.IterateExpression.evaluate(IterateExpression.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.EnablementExpression.evaluate(EnablementExpression.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.evalEnablementExpression(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getShortcutsForSelection(LaunchingResourceManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.computeLabels(LaunchingResourceManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager$1$1.run(LaunchingResourceManager.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Seems more like a bug in the IDe, or possibly a problem caused by incompatible versions of plugings installed into Eclipse / STS. Is there a more detailed message in the error log?

Comment: Error log file is over written with the new error logs, it doesn't show this error log message. Once when this error occurs again, i will get the detailed error log from STS. Is there any way to increase the size of the error log file, so that next time i can retain every thing.